# Install env command

Tags: command-line, coreutils

I want to use `env`, but Ubuntu tells me it is not installed. If I try to install it, Ubuntu tells me there is nothing to do. How to fix this?

```
$ env
The program 'env' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install coreutils

$ sudo apt install coreutils
[sudo] password for jan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
coreutils is already the newest version (8.25-2ubuntu3~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.

$ env
The program 'env' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install coreutils

$ ls -l /usr/bin/env
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/env': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please read `man env` before posting.

Comment: @N0rbert if it's not installed, there won't be any manual to read in the first place

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/env` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: jan@jan-GE60-0NC-GE60-0ND:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/env
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/env': No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's truly missing, like the output of `ls` indicates, you can reinstall coreutils using the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`.

This will simply download the package and reinstall it, overwriting any excisting files and creating any missing.

Comment: thanks a lot you saved me, I had the problem with nohup command and it works fine after that reinstall command.